# How to move/pan OpenGL camera ONLY if right click is held down?

Tags: opengl, glfw, glm-math

My program has a camera that moves/pans when the mouse is moved. How do I get the it to move/pan ONLY if the right mouse click is held down?

This is my function that moves/pans the camera. I tried adding an if statement with the GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT but it doesn't work.

```
static void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
       if (GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && GLFW_PRESS) {
              // variables to store mouse cursor coordinates
              static double previous_xpos = xpos;
              static double previous_ypos = ypos;
              double delta_x = xpos - previous_xpos;
              double delta_y = ypos - previous_ypos;

              // pass mouse movement to camera class
              g_camera.updateYaw(delta_x);
              g_camera.updatePitch(delta_y);

              // update previous mouse coordinates
              previous_xpos = xpos;
              previous_ypos = ypos;
       }
}
```

Not sure if this matters either, but here is my mouse callback. There is a tweakbar in my program.

```
static void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
    {
        // pass mouse data to tweak bar
        TwEventMouseButtonGLFW(button, action);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT` and `GLFW_PRESS` are macros defined using

```
#define GLFW_PRESS 1

#define GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_2

#define GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_2   1
```

So `if (GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && GLFW_PRESS) {`  is  `if( 1 && 1 ) {`  after the preprocessing step of the compiler.

You either need to store the current state of the mouse button  in the mousebutton callback or query the state using [`glfwGetMouseButton`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gac1473feacb5996c01a7a5a33b5066704):

```
if ( glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT) ==  GLFW_PRESS) {
```

Comment: thank you this worked. However, my mouse cursor has disappeared and I cant play around with my tweakbar. Do you know how to make it appear again?

Comment: @Zolly thats another question. You should not ask further different questions, in comments to a question that is not related to that. You probably have `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);` somewhere.